# SSH password-less between all of the nodes

Tags: ssh

I set up passwordless ssh between 3 nodes. node1 can ssh to other without the password but 2 other nodes need to password for ssh to node1. How to fix it? I wanna make ssh connection between all of the nodes together without the need to pass.

Comment: So there is something different between the setups on the different nodes - it's unlikely anyone will be able to guess what based on the information in your question

Comment: I just do these in node1: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""`  `cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`  `chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` `sudo ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub node2@node2` and I don't change sshd_config file.

Comment: did you enable `PubkeyAuthentication` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` ?

Comment: @RoVo, I checked this. it is enabled by "yes"

Comment: did you do the same also from node2 and node3 to node1  ?

Comment: @RoVo. I did the same also from node2 and node3 to node1. Worked. Thankyou.